# Change text colour of dynamically rendered Navigation Menu Item on Click

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

So i have a navigation menu , who's NavigationView is such :-

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
        SubMenu subMenu = m.addSubMenu("Top Playlists");
        subMenu.add("Foo");
        subMenu.add("Bar");
        subMenu.add("Kamehameha");
        MenuItem mi = m.getItem(m.size()-1);
        mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle());
```

So what i'm doing here is i'm dynamically adding Foo , bar , etc as menu items. However , when i click them , they do not get highlighted as the other menu items that have been explicitly declared in the menu layout.

Menu layout :

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

My onNavigationItemSelected :

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
```

Now when i select , foo , bar , etc , they do get selected , however their text color doesn't change. How can i rectify this?
Also , inside onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) , how do i assign behaviour to these dynamically added items , who don't have an item id?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similer problem and I fixed that by calling the method `setCheckedItem(int idRes)` of `NavigationView`. Do something like

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Set the item as checked.
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
```